# Whats wrong with this

Tags: java

It doesnt output anything. If i sound stupid im sorry im still a beginner

```
public class lololo{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String test = "mamara";
        String test2 = "ma";
        int pos = test.indexOf (test2);

        System.out.println(test.substring(0, pos) + test.substring(pos + test.length()));
     }
}
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript. They're similar, but different  (like Ham and Hamburger)

Comment: What do you mean with "no output"? Any errors? Use debugger and post a stack trace...

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `pos`? What do you expect the first `substring` to return? What do you expect the second `substring` call to return?

Comment: check the values of your params, and what impact that has on the printing. It's normal for it to print nothing

Comment: Because `pos` is `0`, and `test.substring(0,0)` will be an empty string and `test.substring(test.length)` will also be an empty string and concatenating two empty strings would give an empty string, thus outputting nothing.

Comment: If I'd be pedantic I'd say it _does_ output something: a newline character :) - You should see an empty line in your command line.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Kindly refrain from using irrelevant tags next time onwards. As for this, you probably wanna figure out first what you exactly want to output, because test.substring(0,pos) would return and empty string and so will test.substring(pos+test.length()). Hence you are getting an empty string as an output, which you probably misunderstood to be not giving any output.

Comment: Oh i see what i did wrong. Thank you so much! @AmoghDixit  Also I'm sorry about the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String test = "mamara";
String test2 = "ma";
int pos = test.indexOf(test2);

System.out.println("Position is: " + pos);

String res1 = test.substring(0, pos);
String res2 = test.substring(pos + test.length());

System.out.println("Result 1 is: " + res1);
System.out.println("Result 2 is: " + res2);
System.out.println("Final result is: " + res1 + res2);
```

The reason you do not see anything is the result equals an empty string.
It means it is "".

Probably your logic of substring method calls is wrong :)